# Create listview from firebase query

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fill my listview with data from firebase query. My code:

```
public class ShowGoalsListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference messages = mDatabase.child("messages");
ArrayList<String> NameList = new ArrayList<String>();;
public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.goals_list);
    ListView animalList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewAnimals);

    getNames();

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, NameList);
    animalList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    animalList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,int position, long arg3)
        {
            String selectedAnimal=NameList.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Animal Selected : "+selectedAnimal,   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

void getNames()
{

    Query queryRef = messages.orderByChild("pages");
    queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Map data = (Map ) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            String name = (String) data.get("name");
            NameList.add(name);
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError){}
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s1){}
        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s2){}
    });
}
}
```

But when I go to my layout this listview is empty. But if I then go to another layout and then came back to goals_list layout listview contains all elements that I need. What can be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. To alert Android that it needs to redraw the list view, you have to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after you change the data of the adapter.

```
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Map data = (Map ) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        String name = (String) data.get("name");
        NameList.add(name);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

To make this work, you'll need to make `arrayAdapter` into ` member field of the activity:

```
public class ShowGoalsListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    ...
```